# Material-UI Typography: Stop wrapping in 4.1.2

Tags: material-ui

I'm using core 4.1.2 and styles 4.1.2
I don't want text to wrap on a usage of:

```
<Typography variant="h6" noWrap={true}>
{this.props.something}
</Typography>
```

The line is breaking before the opening `<Typography>` and items that are in the `<Typography>` component are not wrapping but anything after the component wraps. How do I keep it from wrapping before this component?

I tried `noWrap="true"` and inline="true".

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with CSS on `<Typography />`:

```
.class {
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```